# C++ How does an std::reference_wrapper implicitly convert to reference?

Tags: c++, reference, c++11, implicit-conversion, reference-wrapper

I've recently begun using the `std::reference_wrapper` class. When replacing certain uses of primitive references, I noticed that I did not have to use the `get()` function to pass the reference_wrappers as parameters to functions that take a normal reference.

```
void foo(const T& a);
//...
T obj;
std::reference_wrapper<const T> ref(obj);
foo(ref);  //works!
//foo(ref.get()); also works, but I expected that it would be required
```

How does `std::reference_wrapper` implicitly convert to a primitive reference when it is passed into a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

reference_wrapper includes (§20.8.3):

```
// access
operator T& () const noexcept;
```

This is a conversion operator, and since it isn't specified as `explicit`, it allows implicit conversion from `reference_wrapper<T>` to `T&`.

Answer (score 5):

It overloads this conversion operator:

```
operator T& () const;
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get